# How to create PositiveInteger input in react and material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a `PositiveInteger` input. I bind to `onChange` and basically try to prevent the character to be accepted if it's not forming a positive integer.

This is the code:

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PositiveInteger = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    var newValue = e.target.value;
    if (isNaN(newValue * 1)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setValue(value);
      return;
    }
    if (newValue * 1 <= 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setValue(value);
      return;
    }
    setValue(value);
  };

  return <TextField value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};

export default PositiveInteger;
```

And this is the [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-firefly-finkw?file=/src/PositiveInteger.js:0-558).

But it doesn't work.

So how can I make it only accept positive integeres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PositiveInteger = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    var newValue = Number(e.target.value);
    if (isNaN(newValue) || newValue < 0) { // not integer or negative
      return;
    }
    if (newValue === 0) { // empty input
      setValue("");
    }
    else { // positive integer
      setValue(newValue.toFixed(0));
    }
  };

  return <TextField value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
};

export default PositiveInteger;
```

The main issue with your code was that you were setting the new value for the input no matter if it passed your conditions or not.

Comment: I was setting the old value, as the old value in my code. And I would return. It was `setValue(value)` not `setValue(newValue)`. Even without those lines I would still see the invalid characters being showin in text field.

Comment: Based on your code I realized that my issue was the `initial state`. I have `useState()` which give `undefined` as the initial state, while yours is `useState('')` which gives empty string as the initial state. I changed my code and now it's working.

Comment: Just a side note: `if (isNaN(newValue) || newValue < 0)` checks whether the value is not a *number* (not whether it is nor an *integer*) and is not negative. A positive float number (e.g. `0.25`) would not be discarded. If you want to discart float number you can have something like `if (isNaN(newValue) || newValue < 0 || newValue % 1 > 0)`